# Can't connect to some remote processes

Tags: visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

I am having problems remotely debugging, in VS2008, some web related processes. Other processes on the machine can be debugged. Only some are not that appear to be web related.

(I had an image here of the greyed out processes but not enough reputation :-( )

E.g. if I select one of the w3wp.exe processes the "Attach" button disables.

Anyone got anything to try and help get me access?

I am running msvcmon on the server using authentication disabled and allow any user. Process is written in C++.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out another user had already attached a debugger. If a debugger is already attached to a remote process then the process will not be available to you to attach to. Fair enough. Problem solved :-)